# Lombok: Annotation that generates only few paramteres in Constructor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok, spring-annotations

I want to know if there's an annotation that generates a constructor which contains only, for example, two attributes of my choice. The annotation `@AllArgsConstructor` generates a constructor but with all parameters.

Edit: The solution was found but what if for example, I want a constructor for `(String age, string D)` and one for `(String age, String F)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no such feature and the only way to generate a constructor for the selected fields is by using `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and labeling only and only such fields as `final`.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Foo {

    private final String a;
    private final double b;
    private int c;
}
```

```
new Foo("String", 1.0);
```

However, you don't want to design the class and its fields to satisfy the needs that Lombok doesn't provide.

Comment: Thank you Nikolas. It appears that I found a solution. We can put @NonNull annotation along with @/RequiredArgsConstructor. But I have another question , if for example I wanna generate two constructors for example one for a & b and one for b & c , is there any idea?

Comment: @CompteGmail: Not for now. You need to wrote them manually or generate in the IDE. There are few open tickets in the Lombok Github repository for custom constructors as far as I see.